# access constructor var in static method (es6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Running into a situation where I have the following code:

```
class SomeClass{
    constructor(){
        let name="john doe"
    }

    static newName(){
        //i want to get the "name" variable here   
    }
}
```

In my console.log when i access `newName()`, I'm unable to get the reference of `name` variable which I understand, the class isn't instantiated when I call the static method.  So I guess my question is, what would be the best way for me to go about calling `newName()` and accessing the `name` variable?  I *can* create a variable above the class `let name="john doe"` and access it that way, but i'd like to figure out a way to keep everything confined in the class.

Comment: If it's a static method - then the constructor may have never run. You better explain the original design problem you're trying to solve with this code.

Comment: Please read up about what a `static` method actually is.  It is not attached to an instance of your object at all so it has no instance variables to access.  A class static is like a global method in the class namespace.

Comment: Don't use `Class` in Javascript.

Comment: @PAckerman - `class` is fully supported in ES6.  Your comment is just wrong.

Comment: In addition `let name = "John Doe";` in your constructor just defines a local variable in your constructor function, not an instance property.  Assign `this.name = "John Doe";` if you want an instance property.  But even that won't be accessible from your static method.

Comment: I keep hearing both arguments, use classes, don't use classes.  I've used classes in other OO languages before so i'm trying it out in JS.  But maybe the static approach isn't the way to go in my case.

Comment: I'm confused. You seem to know that something is not possible (*"I'm unable to get the reference of name variable which I understand, the class isn't instantiated when I call the static method."*), yet you are ask how to make it possible. It's not possible.

Comment: @FelixKling I was simply asking, how can I achieve my desired result.  Obviously what I was doing wasn't possible and that's why i came to this forum, to ask how I can accomplish this.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that it isn't clear what the result is you desire. I can tell you that, given the example in your question, there is absolutely no way to access the `name` variable inside the constructor from the static method. The other part is that we don't really know if you familiar with what a static method is and what it means for `name` to be a local variable. I guess if you were then you wouldn't be asking this question. But if you are, then the example and description are poorly chosen and don't clarify your issue at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, let's forget about the `static` for now. So, your class should be like this:

```
class SomeClass {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "john doe";
  }

  newName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

See the variable `name`? If you declare it with `let` (or `var`, or `const`), it would be defined as local variable in the `constructor`. Thus, it can only be used inside the `constructor` method. Now, if you set it with the keyword `this`, it will be defined as an instance variable, therefore, it can be accessed throughout your class.

Let's see now how you can instantiate your class and call the method `newName`:

```
let someClass = new SomeClass(),
    name      = someClass.newName();
```

If you really want to use a static method, keep in mind that everything that happens inside it, is not attached to the instance of the object.

You can read more about es6 classes [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Comment: But what if it was in a different file and you have exported the class that contains the constructor and in the other file you've imported it how can you get name??