# Why static getDerivedStateFromProps does not see local component methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I cannot figure out what is the problem with my component lyfecicle. I need to start my timer `_startTimer` in case when the component will receive new props. But istead of it I always got `null` for my both local methods `_startTimer` and `_clearTimer` in getDerivedStateFromProps react lifecicle method. why?

My problem is about how to use the local methods inside the getDerivedStateFromProps! please, read ceafully before mark my question as dublicated!

Thank you!

```
  _startTimer = timeLeftForNextCD => {
     setInterval(() => {'hey'}, 5000)
  }

  _clearTimer = timerId => {
    clearInterval(timerId)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { timeLeftForNextCD } = this.props.copyProgress
    console.log('componentDidMount', timeLeftForNextCD)
    if (timeLeftForNextCD) {
      this._runTimer(timeLeftForNextCD)
    }
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    const { timeLeftForNextCD } = nextProps.copyProgress
    const { timerId } = prevState
    console.log(this._clearTimer, this._runTimer) // error - null for both
    if (timeLeftForNextCD) {
      this._clearTimer(timerId)
      this._runTimer(timeLeftForNextCD)
    }

    return null
  }
```

Comment: *getDerivedStateFromProps* is a static method, that means it does not belong to an instance of the class, but the class itself. There is no “this” in static methods.

Comment: @PatrickHund ok, but how we can invoke these methods inside the static one? I tried to set them like `console.log(thisComponentName._clearTimer, thisComponentName._runTimer)` but get undefined or `console.log(thisComponentName._clearTimer(), thisComponentName._runTimer())` that they are not a func's

Comment: It's hard to understand from your code what you are trying to achieve, but you are not actually setting the state, are you? Perhaps try using some other lifecycle method, e.g. render

Comment: This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780416/access-constructor-var-in-static-method-es6 and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080168/accessing-previous-props-in-getderivedstatefromprops-method

Comment: @fatahn My problem is about how to use the local methods inside the getDerivedStateFromProps! please, read ceafully before mark my question as dublicated!

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is about how to use the local methods inside the getDerivedStateFromProps!

No, you can't do that. You can't access instance methods inside a static method like `getDerivedStateFromProps`.

`getDerivedStateFromProps` is only for very rare use cases and you shouldn't use it very often.